# Agregar clase si existe un valor o letra específica traído de API con AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un html donde me traigo datos de una API con AJAX, el caso esta es que deseo buscar en dichos datos obtenidos una comprobación de una letra o valor, para así poder agregarle una clase específica si lo consigue, y así poder cambiar los estilos por CSS.

La llamada la estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.com/datos/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                var imp = data[0].dato1;
                    document.getElementById("dato-one").innerHTML = imp;
                    imp = data[0].dato2;
                    document.getElementById("dato-two").innerHTML = imp;

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Sorry si la pregunta es muy básica, estoy algo iniciando, he visto algunos ejemplos y no me ha funcionado.

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Nos puedes indicar exactamente que es lo que no te funciona? Puedes mostrar el html para saber exactamente donde estas colocando los datos y también sería recomendable saber el valor de la variable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber si un string contiene o no un carácter, o una cadena de carácteres yo uso este código:

```
if (strCompleto.indexOf('xxxx')!=-1) {
    console.log("texto encontrado");
    //tu código
    //tuElemento.addClass('tuClase');
    ...
}
else {
    console.log("texto no encontrado");
    //más código
}
```

strCompleto es la variable que contiene el texto donde quiero buscar, y obviamente xxx es el texto que quiero encontrar.

Comment: super! me ha funcionado completamente... te agradezco. aun no puedo dar reputacion. muy amable.